# copy list of files whose paths are in semi colon delimited source.txt file to destination folder keeping their souce paths

Tags: windows, scripting, command-line, dos

i have list of files in test.txt which contains list of file paths in format d:\source\www\default.aspx;d:\source\common\common.js I need to write a bat file to copy these files to destination eg.F:\destination\ whose path is also passed as an parameter to the bat file.I have following script for this `for /f %%l in (somefile.txt) do (
    for %%f in (%%l) do (
        copy "%%f" %1
    )
)`  issue is i need to keep the copy source folder's folder structure in destination folder too. ie above d:\source\www\default.aspx need to copy to f:\destination\www\default.aspx not to f:\destination. Will gratefull if some one can give solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with `xcopy /I "%%f" "%~1\%%~pf"`:

- `xcopy` will create the directory structure for you (without prompting because of the `/I` switch);
- `%%~pf` is the path-only part of the file to copy (see `help for`), appended to your destination base path without any surrounding quotes `%~1`;
- the destination path combination is enclosed in quotes.